# How to kill a Celery task subprocess and still get a proper task state?

Tags: python, task, celery

I am using Celery with a Redis result backend and a RabbitMQ broker. I have a long running task wrapped in a shell script (which in turn calls the program that does the heavy lifting). I want to be able to kill the subprocess from the "outside" but still use Celery's default task states.

My task looks like this:

```py
@app.task(bind=True, base=AbortableTask)
def my_task(self, shellscrippt_wrapper_command):
    proc = subprocess.Popen("exec " + shellscript_wrapper_command,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                            shell=True)

    my_task.cancel_future_calls = call_repeatedly(5, check_abort_state, self.request.id, proc)

    return proc.wait()
```

Helper function:

```
def check_abort_state(task_id, proc):
    result = my_task.AsyncResult(task_id)
    print("*** is aborted? {}, pid: {}".format(result.is_aborted(), proc.pid))
    if result.is_aborted():
        print("*** killing task {}".format(task_id))
        proc.kill()
        my_task.update_state(task_id=task_id, state='FAILURE')
```

---

With `call_repeatedly` I start a timer which checks every five seconds the task's state.

And here is my problem. If I abort the task from the outside (like with `my_task.abort()`) the helper function `check_abort_state` kicks in, detects the **ABORTED** state and kills the subprocess inside the long running task. So far so good. But then the `my_task()` function returns which for Celery means the task was successful and thus sets the state to **SUCCESSFUL** overriding my own **FAILURE** state that I've set in `check_abort_state`. After that I can't do anything any more with the task's state. It is forever set to **SUCCESS**.

Is there any way to prevent that? I'd like to be able to kill the subprocess inside the long running task, but then retain the task state that I have set myself.

One way to avoid it would be instead of `return proc.wait()` do a `raise celery.exceptions.Ignore()` but this in turn ignores *all* task states and then I won't even notice when a task has been successful :/